# New pages not showing up when calling Facebook's accounts endpoint

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of pages using the Facebooks me/accounts endpoint. This has been working fine this far, but now newly created pages (business or non-business) are not showing up in the results.

I have manage_pages and pages_show_list permissions.

What should I do the retrieve all of the pages where the user is either is an admin or has another role?

Comment: i believe there is a bug about that right now

Comment: @luschn do you have a reference to this?

Comment: i just read something about a but in some comments recently, not sure where exactly. check out the bug list on facebook, maybe you can find out about something related to this.

Comment: @luschn Thank you! Perhaps it is this one you saw: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1416251041838883/#_=_

Comment: no, i only saw a comment on stackoverflow, something like "i cannot get all pages" - sorry, that´s all i know :)